# terraform-kubernetes-provider how to create secret from file?

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, terraform-template-file

I'm using the terraform [kubernetes-provider](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/kubernetes) and I'd like to translate something like this `kubectl` command into TF:

```
kubectl create secret generic my-secret --from-file mysecret.json
```

It seems, however the `secret` resource's `data` field [expects only a TF map](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/kubernetes/d/secret.html#data).

I've tried something like

```
data "template_file" "my-secret" {
  template = "${file("${path.module}/my-secret.json")}"
}

resource "kubernetes_secret" "sgw-config" {
   metadata {
     name = "my-secret"
   }
   type = "Opaque"
   data = "{data.template_file.my-secret.template}"
}
```

But it complains that this is *not* a map.  So, I can do something like this:

```
   data = {
      "my-secret.json" = "{data.template_file.my-secret.template}"
   }
```

But this will write the secret with a top-level field named `my-secret.json` and when I volume mount it, it won't work with other resources.

What is the trick here?

Answer (score 10):

as long the file is UTF-8 encoded  you can use something like this

```
resource "kubernetes_secret" "some-secret" {

      metadata {
        name      = "some-secret"
        namespace = kubernetes_namespace.some-ns.metadata.0.name
        labels = {
          "sensitive" = "true"
          "app"       = "my-app"
        }
      }
      data = {
        "file.txt" = file("${path.cwd}/your/relative/path/to/file.txt")
      }
    }
```

If the file is a binary one you will have an error like

> Call to function "file" failed: contents of
>   /your/relative/path/to/file.txt are not valid UTF-8; use the
>   filebase64 function to obtain the Base64 encoded contents or the other
>   file functions (e.g. filemd5, filesha256) to obtain file hashing
>   results instead.

I tried encoding the file in base64 but then the problem is that the resulting text will be re-encoded in base64 by the provider. So I guess there is no solution for binary files at the moment...
I'll edit with what I find next for binaries.

Comment: related issue: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-kubernetes/issues/901

Answer (score 2):

Just use
https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/kubernetes/r/config_map.html#binary_data

```
resource "kubernetes_config_map" "example" {

  metadata {
    name = "my-config"
  }

  binary_data = {
    "my_payload.bin" = "${filebase64("${path.module}/my_payload.bin")}"
  }
}
```

Comment: right idea to use `binary_data`, in April 2021 this field added to the resource [kubernetes_secret](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/kubernetes/latest/docs/resources/secret#binary_data) - so this should be used here, as that is what the OP was asking for - not `kubernetes_config_map`.

Answer (score 2):

This might be a bit off-topic, but I've been facing similar problem except that the file might not be present in which case the `terraform [plan|apply]` fails.

To be exact: I needed to duplicate a secret from one namespace to another one.

I realized that by using [`hashicorp/external`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/external/latest/docs/data-sources/data_source) provider.

The steps are pretty simple:

1. Load `data` by calling external program
2. Refer to the `data` in `kubernetes_secret` resource

The program should accept (and process) JSON on STDIN and produce valid JSON on STDOUT as response to the parameters passed-in in the STDIN's JSON.

Example shell script:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

set -e

/bin/echo -n '{ "token": "'
kubectl get -n consul secrets/hashicorp-consul-bootstrap-acl-token --template={{.data.token}}
/bin/echo -n '"}'
```

tarraform source:

```
data "external" "token" {
  program = ["sh", "${path.module}/consul-token.sh"]
}

resource "kubernetes_secret" "consul-token" {
  depends_on = [data.external.token]

  metadata {
    name      = "consul-token"
    namespace = "app"
  }

  data = {
    token = base64decode(data.external.token.result.token)
  }
}
```

and requirements:

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    external = {
      source  = "hashicorp/external"
      version = ">= 2.0.0"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can use binary_data attribute in the secret now.
e.g.

```
binary_data = {
    "my_payload.bin" = "${filebase64("${path.module}/my_payload.bin")}"
}
```

reference:
https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-kubernetes/pull/1228
https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/kubernetes/latest/docs/resources/secret#binary_data

Answer (score -2):

Basically you need to provide a map like this :

```
resource "kubernetes_secret" "sgw-config" {
   metadata {
     name = "my-secret"
   }
   type = "Opaque"
   data {
           "key1" = "value1"
           "key2" = "value2"
  }
}
```

you can refer to your internal variables using

```
resource "kubernetes_secret" "sgw-config" {
       metadata {
         name = "my-secret"
       }
       type = "Opaque"
       data {
               "USERNAME" = "${var.some_variable}"
               "PASSWORD" = "${random_string.root_password.result}"
      }
    }
```

Comment: sorry to downvote but this is not addressing the question: how to add a file (possibly non UTF-8) as a value of a secret using Terraform?

Answer (score -2):

It seems if you run the command `kubectl create secret generic my-secret --from-file mysecret.json`

and then

```
$ kubectl get secrets my-secret -o yaml
apiVersion: v1
data:
  my-secret.json: ewogICA.....
kind: Secret
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: "2019-03-25T18:20:43Z"
  name: my-secret
  namespace: default
  resourceVersion: "67026"
  selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/default/secrets/my-secret
  uid: b397a29c-4f2a-11e9-9806-000c290425d0
type: Opaque
```

it stores it similarly with the filename as the single key.  When I mount this in a volume/volumeMount it works as expected.  I was afraid that it wouldn't but when I create the secret using the `--from-file` argument, this is exactly how it stores it.